# How to use Russian Doll caching on same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2 web app.
In this app I am using the russian doll style of caching.

I am fetching projects in a table list and records are cached. The problem is that
when I am for example changing the title of a record the title in the list is not updated.
If this were a association I would use :touch => true but it´s the same model.

This is how I start the listing:

```
<%= render @projects %>
```

This is the projects.html.erb template:

```
<% cache projects do %>
  <%= render project %>
<% end %>
```

This is the project.html.erb template:

```
<% cache project do %>
<tr>
 <td><%= link_to project.title.capitalize, admin_project_path(project) %></td>
 <td><%= project.reference %></td>
 <td><%= show_status project.status %></td>
</tr>   
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thankful for all input.